# Change style of an element when hover another element is not working

Tags: css

I created a triangle and it seems that the usual `.something:hover .another{...}` is not working on it, does anyone know what is the problem here?

```css
.actions {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 260px;
}

.action-reg-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 45px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 150ms;
}

.action-log-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  background-color: #0D5E5E;
  transition: 150ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 37.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  right: -1px;
  border-right: 40px solid #0D5E5E;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 150ms;
  z-index: 20;
}

.action-reg-button:hover {
  color: #b2b2b2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action-log-button:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

.action-log-button:hover .triange-left {
  border-right: 40px solid #2e2e2e!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <p class="action-reg-button">Register</p>
  <div class="triangle">
    <div class="triangle-left"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="action-log-button" id="login-menu-button">Login</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issues

The selector:

```
.action-log-button:hover .triange-left {...
```

would imply this non-existent layout:

```
<p class="action-log-button" id="login-menu-button">
Login <div class="triangle-left"></div>
</p>
```

CSS styles has a flow that cascades, meaning if you want to act upon a tag but affect an entirely different tag doing so, then you must ensure that the tag that gets affected follows or is a descendant of the tag your are acting upon.

So take a look at your layout it appears that hovering over `.action-log-button` could never affect `.triangle-left` because `.action-log-button` follows `.triangle` and `.triangle` is the tag to traverse to get to `.triangle-left`. Basically `.tringle` must be within `.action-log-button` or be placed after `.action-log-button`.

---

#### Solution

Place the HTML of `.action-log-button` right before `.triangle`* and use this ruleset:

```
.action-log-button:hover+.triangle .triangle-left {
  border-right-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

*<sup>I know having the triangle sit after the button isn't what you want but read on</sup>

This means:

- hover over `.action-log-button`
- then go to `+ .triangle` that's directly after
- and them go inside `.triangle` to reach `.triangle-left`
- and change its `border-right-color: #2e2e2e;`.
- Note the change from `border-right: 40px solid #2e2e2e;`
- as well as the changes in `.triangle-left` -- by separating the rulesets from shorthand we simplify the complexity of style which is less error prone.

Finally, in order to rectify the triangle and button swapping locations, we'll use the flexbox property: `order` In a default flow of DOM tags, the order goes from left to right then top to bottom. If you assign the flex-items (term for the tags that are the direct children of flex-container (term for a tag that has `display: flex`)) an `order` number, they will take those positions. So we'll assign `.action-log-button` `order: 3` and `.triangle` `order: 2`. Although it will appear properly when rendered on a webpage, the positions in HTML are were the tags are in reality.

---

#### Demo

**BTW** the HTML tags are changed to more semantically sound types. Using `<p>` or `<div>` as a button is really bad. It's valid but it's just the worst.

```css
.actions {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 260px;
}

.action-reg-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 45px 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  order: 1
}

.action-log-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px;
  background-color: #0D5E5E;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  order: 3
}

.triangle {
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  order: 2
}

.triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right-width: 40px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-color: #0D5E5E;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.action-reg-button:hover {
  color: #b2b2b2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action-log-button:hover+.triangle .triangle-left {
  border-right-color: #2e2e2e;
}

button {
  display: block;
}

.triangle-left {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="actions">

  <button class="action-reg-button">Register</button>


  <button class="action-log-button">Login</button>

  <section class='triangle'>
    <div class="triangle-left"></div>
  </section>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, sir! I will take into consideration your advice and learn all the semantics.

Comment: Gr8! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

in single css you can't do that:

```
.action-log-button:hover .triange-left {
  border-right: 40px solid #2e2e2e!important;
}
```

first you have to make your `.triangle-left` as parent block for your Login button like this:

```
<div class="actions">
     <p class="action-reg-button">Register</p>
     <div class="triangle">
       <div class="triangle-left">
           <p class="action-log-button" id="login-menu-button">Login</p>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

second, make `.triangle-left` shape as you want, in this case css should look something like his :

```
.triangle-left {
    border-bottom: 37px solid #0D5E5E;;
    border-left: 45px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 80px;
}
```

and then you can make hover on this block:

```
.triangle-left:hover {
    border-bottom: 37px solid #2e2e2e;
}
```

now you have same shape but just as one block

Comment: Did it work for you? I've tried to put these styles into ```triangle-left:hover{these styles}``` but it doesn't work. Or did I misunderstood what you've meant?

Comment: Thank you! It works, although I've placed login button inside ```div.triangle``` to make stand in one line with the triangle left.